# "One of them was/were you"

Tags: personal-pronouns

If I am talking to somebody about a certain group of people in the third person, and then want to refer to the person I am talking with as one of those people, which do I say?

> One of them **were** you
>
> One of them **was** you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb must agree with the subject 'one', therefore it's 'one of them was you'.

Comment: Thanks! But why is it 'one' it has to agree with, and not 'you'?

Comment: I don't think *you* is subject here. Try replacing *you* by a different person.
I would say *one of them was him* : *him* is an object.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd say that the general rule is that the verb in English agrees with the subject, not the complement. In the sentence you are mentioning, 'you' is a complement.

Comment: @ Laure: the verb 'be' cannot have an object.

Comment: @ Irene: Quite right, thanks. It is attribute, isn't it? It is not subject anyway.

Comment: This confuses me, too. Would you say "One of the boys were those Indians" or "One of those boys was those Indians"? The first one jumps to me as correct (or hell, better yet, "One of them was an Indian", but that's not the point)

Comment: Can 'one boy' be 'those Indians'? Isn't this ungrammatical? There's something wrong with the use of the plural form in 'Indians' I think. Seems to me that'One of them was an Indian' is the only correct sentence here

Comment: The verb agrees with the subject rather than the complement unless the subject is a word like there, what, who, ... For example, "What is required are fortitude and imagination."

Comment: "One of those boys were those Indians" can't be correct, since "one of those boys" must be "one boy", and one person cannot be a group of persons. Multiple personalities excepted, of course, but that's a special circumstance. What is happening is the natural (lazy, but natural) tendency to match "boys" to "those Indians". The sentence should be "One of those boys was with those Indians", or "One of those boys belonged to that group of Indians."

Comment: @Laure In "one of them was him," the *him* is not the object; rather, it's the **predicate noun**, restating the subject of the sentence. And for this reason, technically the correct way to say that sentence is "one of them was **he**", but you'll rarely see this usage.

Answer (score 1):

"One of them" is a noun phrase referring to a single person. Therefore all its verbs are always singular.

This is correct:

> One of them was you.

This is not:

> <strike>One of them were you.</strike>