# An adjective meaning “present at the place in question”

Tags: single-word-requests

> One of the employees **who were attendant at the meeting** asked a
> question.

I am looking for an adjective for ‘the employee’ that means ‘who was attendant at the meeting’.

The best I could find was ‘attendant’ itself, but as an adjective it means ‘accompanying’ which is not exactly the same as what I want. Also, I am not sure if ‘present’ is the best choice in that context?

Comment: Also, it should be 'one of the employee**s**'.

Comment: Also, it should be *One of the employees who **were**...*

Comment: @TinfoilHat No, in this case, the past tense verb should be singular because it pertains to the singular "one (of the)" rather than the plural "employees". See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46040/one-of-them-was-were-you#:~:text=1.%20%22One%20of%20them%22%20is%20a%20noun%20phrase,is%20not%3A%20One%20of%20them%20were%20you.%20Share.

Comment: @Deepak — No, not if we're talking about employees who were at the meeting. The relative clause agrees with *employees*: *Of **the employees who were at the meeting**, one asked a question.* See: [“You're one of the only people” plurality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524090/youre-one-of-the-only-people-plurality/524298#524298)

Comment: @TinfoilHat I can see your point. It can perhaps go both ways. The way the sentence is constructed, I will concede you are right, the plural sounds more natural. But if we were envisioning a meeting where not all the employees were present (say a special or off-site meeting), then the singular would be correct. I guess I would emphasise that with punctuation: "One of the employees, who was at the meeting, asked a question." Replacing "the" with "our" somehow makes it sound even more natural: "One of *our* employees, who was at the meeting, asked a question." English is a funny old language.

Comment: @Deepak — We can always skirt the issue by reducing the relative clause: *One of the employees at the meeting asked a question*. Or we can remove the issue by rewording: *An employee who was at the meeting asked a question.*

Answer (score 14):

> ?*One of the employees **who were attendant at the meeting** asked a question.*

This is rather unnatural.

If you want an adjective, it should be "present":

> *One of the employees **present** asked a question.*

Or if it doesn't have to be an adjective, you can do without one:

> *One of the employees **at the meeting** asked a question.*

> *One of the employees **there** asked a question.*

Comment: Curious how *one of the employees present* and *one of the present employees*  mean two totally different things.

Comment: @tchrist Tell me about it.

Comment: Ghost of Christmas present...

Comment: @TinfoilHat Don't forget the Ghost of Chrismas prescient.

Answer (score 9):

This is a short expression that is apparently the best that can be found; it is as good as an adjective.

> ([merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20attendance)) **in attendance**
>
> **1**: present at an event, meeting, etc.
>
> - Everyone in attendance voted in favor of the measure.
> - A number of celebrities were in attendance.

- One of the employees in attendance  asked a question.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Perspectives_on_Diversity_Equity_and_Soc/WX82DgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22people+in+attendance%22&pg=PA70&printsec=frontcover)) The gym was over half full (more than thousand people in attendance) and most of the people in attendance were white.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Carson_National_Forest_N_F_Western_Spruc/Iyg3AQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22people+in+attendance%22&pg=PT57&printsec=frontcover))   The meeting started at 7:30 p.m. with five people in attendance

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/People_from_Bloomington/SfE3EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22people+in+attendance%22&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover)) The total number of people in attendance at the funeral home confirmed that the news of Mrs. Elberhart's death hadn't attracted much attention

[refs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22people%20in%20attendance%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

However, this acception of "in attendance" could be particular to AmE. For instance, the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-attendance) does not mention the  sense found in the Merriam-Webster dictionary, nor does [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-attendance).

Comment: Oxford (as reported by [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+attendance%22&oq=%22in+attendance%22&aqs=chrome..69i64j69i57.4109j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) gives ‘present at a function or a place’ as its first definition, confirming my feeling that that meaning is well known in BrE too. (To me it feels slightly formal, though.)

Comment: @gidds The result from using the link is only "to be in attendance" from Longman. (be in attendance (at something) _formal_ to be at a special or important event.

Comment: Maybe Google shows different dictionaries to different people. For me (in the UK), it says _“Definitions from Oxford Languages”_; it defines only _“in attendance”_, and the first definition it gives is _“1. present at a function or a place.”_ with the example _“some 200 were in attendance at the fourteenth reunion”_ — no mention of formality.

Comment: @gidds There is no doubt then, it is known in BrE too.

Answer (score 1):

Attendant works fine as an adjective. See [Collins for the entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/attendant).

> An attendant employee asked a question at the meeting.

or you could use the related participle 'attending'

> An attending employee asked a question at the meeting.

Or use the related nomial form 'attendee' if employee is clear from context:

> An attendee asked a question at the meeting.

All are not only comprehensible, but shorter as a nomial modifier than using the additional clause.

Comment: Note that "attending" gets an ideosyncractic meaning when it modifies "physician".

Comment: I would find the first two examples unusual enough that I would guess it was supposed to be 'An attentive employee...'.

Comment: @dbmag9 No doubt the language is bookish. You won't hear it in the county jail. But there's a difference in meaning between attendant (sense: one who attends) and attentive (sense: one who pays attention). Not all attendees are attentive, in which case you could say confusingly 'Not all attendees are attendant' if by attendant you use the alternative sense of attendant that means attentive. :D

Comment: @dbmag9 Personally, it seems redundant to me in minutes to point out that someone who is asking a question at a meeting is in attendance unless there's participation from someone teleconferencing? The shortest way to tackle the minutes would be to say 'Bob asked a question' to be short and specific in the general case.

Comment: @JD I understand the difference but I wouldn't call your examples bookish; I would call them unnatural and clunky. From a good native writer I would suspect an autocorrect or editing error; from a writer I didn't know I would suspect they learned English as a foreign language.

Comment: @dbmag9 Well, you're certainly entitled to your impressions. All I can say is that modern English ranges from Shakespearean English in which place "visages are countenanced" to the Victorian elaboration of American authors like Emerson's largely semi-colon and colon cobbled-together sesquipedalia, to the curt grammar of Strunk, White, and Hemingway. The word is obviously in the dictionary, and given all of the British English literature I've read like that of Jane Eyre or Return of the Native, all I can say is it sounds perfectly natural to me to use attendant in that sense...

Comment: "unnatural and clunky" is largely prescriptivist and somewhat ego-centric sounding, and seems to be ignorant of the vast range of dialect that English is subject to, from the constructions from Scots that bleeds into English, to Indian-isms, to literate constructions one often finds in obscure books in distinct language communities.

Comment: I live on the Southside of Chicago, and cockneyed English sounds at times baffling unlike English at all, so it's very unnatural to me. But were I from London, I'm sure the idiom that I'm comfortable understanding from the housing projects here in the city would be equally unnatural.

Comment: @dbmag9 In short, your [idiolect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiolect) is one member of a fuzzy group of a dialect which is one aspect of a fuzzy group of a language, so I'd be cautious drawing too much certainty of what unnatural and clunky is by presuming your idiolect is somehow more accurate than other peoples'. That's why usage panels are composed of many people, and not just one. Language is socially constructed knowledge.